# Constraining interactive camera motion in Gazebo Sim, to keep the camera inside an indoor setting

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin, gazebo-gui

I am running a Gazebo Sim simulation in an indoor setting and I would like to restrain the camera movement (pan, zoom etc) to this environment, so that I cannot accidentally zoom or pan to the outside.

1. Is this existing Gazebo Sim functionality?

   - I don't think so, as the [`InteractiveViewControl` plugin](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-gui/blob/gz-gui7/src/plugins/interactive_view_control/InteractiveViewControl.cc) does not seem to have min/max settings for camera positions, and neither does the SDFormat specification, nor the [`OrbitViewController`](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-rendering/blob/gz-rendering7/src/OrbitViewController.cc).
2. Or would someone happen to know of an existing plugin for this?

Alternatively I consider to adapt a local copy of the `InteractiveViewControl` plugin. On first sight it seems that I would have to check the camera position after [this](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-gui/blob/c020e25a48c80b4344474f6ceebe870cc8e13b66/src/plugins/interactive_view_control/InteractiveViewControl.cc#L271), [this](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-gui/blob/c020e25a48c80b4344474f6ceebe870cc8e13b66/src/plugins/interactive_view_control/InteractiveViewControl.cc#L292), [this](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-gui/blob/c020e25a48c80b4344474f6ceebe870cc8e13b66/src/plugins/interactive_view_control/InteractiveViewControl.cc#L298) and [this](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-gui/blob/c020e25a48c80b4344474f6ceebe870cc8e13b66/src/plugins/interactive_view_control/InteractiveViewControl.cc#L310) line, and each time add a conditional `this->camera->WorldPosition()` before the `UpdateReferenceVisual()` call, to constrain the camera pose if needed.

I think:

- For pan it should be relatively straightforward, just clamp x, y and z to [min,max],
- But for zoom and especially for orbit I am not sure, I think in both cases maybe translate along the camera-target vector until the position is within the bounding box?

Furthermore: would someone have an example `CMakeLists.txt` to compile an `gz-gui` plugin outside Gazebo the source tree? For a `gz-sim` plugin I eventually found the [ros_gz_project_template](https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz_project_template/blob/main/ros_gz_example_gazebo/CMakeLists.txt) but that is a `gz-sim` plugin, not a `gz-gui` plugin. Or is the only needed change to that `CmakeLists.txt` just to link with `gz-gui` instead of `gz-sim`?

Comment: 1. Gazebo doesn't have settings for this.
If you are modifying the InteractiveViewControl plugin, maybe at the end of the onRender function, you can check the camera world pose there and clamp the xyz values (instead of clamping after Pan, Orbit, Zoom)?

For an example CMakeLists.txt, you can check out the [standalone examples](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-gui/tree/gz-gui7/examples/plugin) in gz-gui.